# Where can I find all the values I can put in role attribute in XSL FO for an accessible document?

Tags: pdf, accessibility, xsl-fo

I am trying to create an accessible document and have a list of requirements. There are some roles that I do not know how to apply to a block of text (caption, formula, etc - I saw the types in Adobe DC when clicking the structure tree and right clicking on an element.) Right now I only know how to add these types: *paragraph, headings, artifact, Lbody, Li, lbl, part*.

Role attribute I am talking about: https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#role

The only useful information I found is on this link:https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.7/accessibility.html under **Customized Tagging**

Thanks.

Comment: You could also have a look at xep from renderx: http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#Accessibility

Comment: I am not going to comment on FOP implementation as it is not possible to express all things "really required" in Accessibility through a single attribute "role". I work for RenderX and I can tell you that the proper XSL FO to Accessible implementation requires extensions as they are implemented in RenderX. You will likely only be able to meet some basic requirements using some basic documents otherwise.

Comment: and As a for instance, anything at all that requires a secondary input is really not possible. Think ... I have an abbreviation (OK) but I want it read this way = 2 pieces of information, not one. Unless they process the role attribute in some way like allowing you to write role="abbreviation:General Electric" and chunk that apart, forget it. And you have not even cracked the surface of all things that require multiple inputs like artifacts, abbreviations, alternate-descriptions, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard tags are defined in the PDF specifications.  See the links to the PDF 1.7 spec and the near-equivalent ISO 32000-1 specification at https://www.pdfa.org/resource/iso-32000-1-pdf-1-7/

ISO 14289 (PDF/UA) defines features of accessible PDF beyond just adding tags.  See https://www.pdfa.org/resource/iso-14289-pdfua/

The Matterhorn Protocol defines a checklist of ways that a PDF document can fail to conform to ISO 14289.  See https://www.pdfa.org/resource/the-matterhorn-protocol/

PAC 2021 from the PDF/UA Foundation (https://pdfua.foundation/en) is a free (Windows-only) tool that checks PDF/UA conformance of a PDF file.  It does the 'machine' checks from the Matterhorn Protocol and also tries to check some of the Matterhorn Protocol checks that are defined for being done by a human, with varying success.  I haven't used this version much, but previous PAC versions had bugs about handling Ruby tags.

AH Formatter has a default mapping of FOs to PDF tags.  The `axf:pdftag` extension property can override the defaults.  For better accessibility, you also need to do things like provide alternate text for graphics, use `xml:lang` or `language` to indicate the language, etc.  See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-pdf.html#taggedpdf